# howto handle objects asp.net javascript highcharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm trying to create a chart with values from my database.
On the server side I throw the values in a list and pass the list to the client.
But somehow the chart just won't display anything at all.

Here's my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#but").click(function (e) {
        getData();
    });
});


function CreateTempChart(options) {

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 25,
            marginBottom: 25,
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'in °C'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.options.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.x + ': ' + this.y;
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -50,
            y: 40,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series:[]
    });
    chart.addSeries(options);

};

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "BasicLine",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {

            var yo = JSON.parse(result);
            var arr = [];

            $.map(yo, function (item) {
                var t = item.Time.replace("\/Date(", "").replace(")\/", "");
                var obj = {
                    name: "Temperature",
                    data: item.Value,
                    categories: t
                };
                arr.push(obj);
            });

            var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(arr);
            console.log(jsonArray);
            CreateTempChart(jsonArray);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("oh no");
        }
    });
}
```

The log looks like this

```
[{"name":"Temperature","data":10.7,"categories":"1430408770000"},{"name":"Temperature","data":10.8,"categories":"1430408990000"},....]
```

Any ideas? I'm not quite familiar with js.

Comment: No error message in console? `categories` is not a feature of a series, but should be defined for the axis. Although it looks like you are attempting to use `datetime`? The `data` field should be an array. In general the series you are trying to add are not formatted correctly.

Comment: no.. no error message at all... ya I read a couple of times xAxis.categories = time... but this is not workin at all. I think the reason could be because name, series, data are defined as string?

Comment: i recommend to test with some sample data to check if the plugin is working fine or not , then test with database ..